# ag-grid: Getting list of columns on which sorting is applied

Tags: javascript, sorting, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

How do I get the list of columns on which sorting is applied, in ag-grid. There is an api (onSortChanged) and an event (sortChanged). But neither is helpful in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gridApi.getSortModel()`, which returns you an array containing all column Ids and sort direction like below.

```
[
 {colId: "country", sort: "asc"},
 {colId: "athlete", sort: "asc"}
]
```

Comment: Yeah. That's it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

AG Grid: as of version 24.0.0, `getSortModel()` is deprecated, sort information is now part of Column State. Use `columnApi.getColumnState()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the status of particular grid column - `sort` status etc using :-

```
params.columnApi.getColumnState();
```

The default value is `null`. "asc" or "desc" are other sort status.

Answer (score 2):

You can find in the following way

```
const listOfSortModel = gridParams.columnApi.getColumnState().filter(s => s.sort !== null)
```