# ag-grid-react: getSortModel is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to get sort model from ag-grid-react component using getSortModel() but I'm getting getSortModel is not a function

my code

```
 onSortChanged={useCallback(e => console.log(e.api.getSortModel(), 'im from sort'))}
```

"@ag-grid-community/react": "27.3.0",
"@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "27.3.0",

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70032627/13405106) answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spend some time found `params.api.getSortModel()` is deprecated after version 24.0.0.

Using Column state for get Sort model and set Sort model in the following way

**getSortModel:**

```
   const onSortChanged = useCallback(() => {
        const value = gridParams.columnApi.getColumnState().find(s => s.sort != null)
        if (value) {
            setSortModel([ value ])
        } else {
            setSortModel([])
        }
    }, [ gridParams, setSortModel ])
```

**setSortModel:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (sortModel.length > 0) {
       const curretSortModel = gridParams.columnApi.getColumnState()
       const mergeSortModel = curretSortModel.map(o1 => sortModel.find(o2 => o2.colId === o1.colId) || o1)
       gridParams.columnApi.setColumnState(mergeSortModel)
     }
}, [gridParams, sortModel]
```

we are setting gridParems using **onGridReady()** method

```
const [ gridParams, setGridParams ] = useState()


const onGridReady = useCallback(params => {
    setGridParams(params)
}, [])


<Grid
    onGridReady={onGridReady} // using this we are setting gridParams
    rowData={dataset}
    floatingFilter
    sideBar={GRID_SIDE_BAR}
    onSelectionChanged={getSelectedRowData}
    enableSelect={true}
    onFilterChanged={onFilterChanged}
    onSortChanged={onSortChanged}
    rowSelection={'multiple'}
    licenseKey={'test'}
    getRowId={getRowNodeId}
    onColumnVisible={onColumnVisible}
    onColumnResized={onColumnResized}
    onColumnMoved={onColumnMoved}
    columnDefs={mappedColDefs}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    cacheQuickFilter={true}
    frameworkComponents={{
        customLoadingOverlay: () => <Paper><Typography>Please wait while your requests are loading...</Typography></Paper>,
        customNoRowsOverlay: () => <Paper><Typography>No requests found</Typography></Paper>
    }}
    loadingOverlayComponent={'customLoadingOverlay'}
    noRowsOverlayComponent={'customNoRowsOverlay'}
/>
```

Comment: so how do you perish the gridParams object value across the component, can u pls elaborate? like how will you the gridParams first from Grid table and assign to a new variaable and use like that, TIA. <3

Answer (score 1):

As per this plunkr, you can retrieve and apply sort with the following example: https://plnkr.co/edit/?open=index.jsx&preview

```
 const sortByAthleteDesc = useCallback(() => {
    gridRef.current.columnApi.applyColumnState({
      state: [{ colId: 'athlete', sort: 'desc' }],
      defaultState: { sort: null },
    });
  }, []);


  const saveSort = useCallback(() => {
    var colState = gridRef.current.columnApi.getColumnState();
    var sortState = colState
      .filter(function (s) {
        return s.sort != null;
      })
      .map(function (s) {
        return { colId: s.colId, sort: s.sort, sortIndex: s.sortIndex };
      });
    savedSort = sortState;
    console.log('saved sort', sortState);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Vue JS :

```
const onSortChanged = () => {
  window.colState = gridApi.value.getColumnState();
  let newSortedState = window.colState
    .filter(function (s) {
      return s.sort != null;
    })
    .map(function (s) {
      return { colId: s.colId, sort: s.sort, sortIndex: s.sortIndex };
    });
  console.log('column state saved', newSortedState);
};
```

Template:

```
<ag-grid-vue
    :gridOptions="gridOptions"
    :columnDefs="props?.columns"
    :icons="icons"
    :rowHeight="props?.rowHeight"
    style="height: 500px"
    :enableRangeSelection="false"
    :rowSelection="'multiple'"
    :rowMultiSelectWithClick="false"
    class="ag-theme-quartz"
    :paginationPageSizeSelector="[3, 5, 10, 15, 25, 50]"
    :sideBar="sideBar"
    @grid-ready="handleGridReady"
    @selection-changed="handleSelectionChange"
    :defaultColDef="props?.defaultColDef"
    @sortChanged="onSortChanged"
    :rowModelType="rowModelType"
    :pagination="true"
    :paginationPageSize="paginationPageSize"
    @filter-changed="onFilterChanged"
  />
```